# Handle scrollbar in selemium2

Tags: scrollbar, selenium-webdriver

How I can get scrollbar within div element using selenium webdriver and firefox browser?
I need to validate case: scroll bar will appear when table (table located inside div) has more then 10 rows.

Comment: You can probably refer http://selenium-automation.blogspot.in/2010/10/selenium-automation-problems.html to check the visibility of the scrollbar.  Use JavascriptExecutor for webdriver.  Or publish your html..

Comment: Thanks. Comparing clientHeight and scrollHeight gives me the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if developed is publishing the scroll bar properties in HTML properties, then you will be able to capture, else you will have to discuss with developers.
After that you can get the row count using webdriver method

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("XPATH expression")).size();
```

and using a if condition You can validate the scroll bar.

Thanks

Comment: Div element has css value overflow-y: scroll;
But I dont know how to check scrollbar status: is it active or no...